# Extracting numbers from string - Why do I get two arrays when using a capture group?

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all, preg-grep

I am trying to extract numbers from a mix string.

```
<?php
$string = "c <a data-player-id=\"5528\" href=\"/players/5528-ga-name--5406546\" target=\"_self\">GA Name</a> b <a data-player-id=\"8992842\" href=\"/players/8992842-chandran-win--123345\" target=\"_self\">C Win</a>";

//preg_match_all('!\d+!', $string, $matches);
//preg_match_all('/data-player-id=\"(\d+)/', $string, $matches);
preg_match_all('/\/players\/(\d+)/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);

?>
```

But it results into 2 arrays:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => /players/5528
        [1] => /players/8992842
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5528
        [1] => 8992842
    )

)
```

I want to capture numbers like `5528` and `8992842`. The code below did not work.

```
 /*
 $zero = $matches[0];
 $one = $matches[1];
 $two = $matches[2];

 echo $zero;
 echo $one;
 echo $two;
 */
```

Edit :
Any idea why it returns into 2 arrays ?
Is it possible to count the items in `array[1]` ?

Comment: `echo $matches[1][0];` and `echo $matches[1][1];`

Comment: As already mentioned, the reason is that you use a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) for extraction. `$matches[1]` always contains matches of the first parenthesized group (capturing group), `$matches[0]` contains the full pattern matches. It's possible to do it without capturing group by use of [`\K` which resets](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) beginning of the reported match, thus returns only the numbers in `$matches[0]` [see this demo at regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/FV3kke/1). To count them, just use use `count($matches[0])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop print all found value in `$matches[1]`

Try

```
$string = "c <a data-player-id=\"5528\" href=\"/players/5528-ga-name--5406546\" target=\"_self\">GA Name</a> b <a data-player-id=\"8992842\" href=\"/players/8992842-chandran-win--123345\" target=\"_self\">C Win</a>";


preg_match_all('/\/players\/(\d+)/', $string, $matches);
//print_r($matches);


foreach($matches[1] as $match)
{
    echo $match."<br />";
}
```

[output](https://eval.in/702512)

**UPDATE 1**

Yes, you can count the elements found in `$matches[1]` by using [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

```
$total_matches = count($matches[1]);
echo $total_matches;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. any idea why it returns into 2 array ?

Comment: is it possible to count the items in array[1] ?

Comment: @DilDilshan yes it is possible. Please see update 1 in my answer

Comment: how can i extract first letter before <a data-player   (c and b) in my case. preg_match_all ('/^(.*)<a/U', $string, $matches); it only gives me "c"

Answer (score 2):

Try to something like this.

```
<?php
$string = "c <a data-player-id=\"5528\" href=\"/players/5528-ga-name--5406546\" target=\"_self\">GA Name</a> b <a data-player-id=\"8992842\" href=\"/players/8992842-chandran-win--123345\" target=\"_self\">C Win</a>";

preg_match_all('!\d+!', $string, $matches);

$arr = array_unique($matches[0]);

// For Count items...
$count = count($arr);
echo $count;

foreach($arr as $match)
{
    echo $match."<br />";
}
?>
```

**Output**

5528

5406546

8992842

123345

Comment: any idea why it returns into 2 array and also is it possible to count the items in array[1] ?

Comment: $match[0] contains array of strings that matched full pattern, and $match[1] contains array of strings enclosed by tag.  Use count($arr) function for count the items